# attend or attended in "He had persuaded himself that the festivities that attend this season were vulgar and barbaric"

Tags: tense, comparison

> The result was that Philip had nowhere to go, and he spent Christmas
>   Day in his lodgings. Under Hayward's influence he had persuaded
>   himself that the festivities that **attend** this season were vulgar and
>   barbaric, and he made up his mind that he would take no notice of the
>   day; but when it came, the jollity of all around affected him
>   strangely.
>
> *Of Human Bondage by W. Somerset Maugham*

Can I use the past tense "**attended**" here instead of "**attend**"? If so, what would be the difference between using the past tense and present tense here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attend** there means "accompany".  The verb is slightly formal in register but not an archaism.

The present tense there is used to convey customary aspect.  These festivities are regularly and customarily part of the season. So the sentence is correct as is.

There is no need for the verb to be recast in the past tense because of "had persuaded".

Compare:

**He had persuaded himself that the cheese which *is* produced in this part of Switzerland was the best in the world.

[*] He had persuaded himself that the cheese which *was* produced in this part of Switzerland was the best in the world.**

"*was* the best in the world" is in the past tense because it is reported speech or reported opinion.  That the cheese is produced in this part of Switzerland is fact and therefore not within the scope of the opinion.

Answer (score -1):

First, be aware that this use of "attend" is archaic.

To answer your question, present and past tense yield pretty much the same meaning here. The only minor distinction is that "attend" implies a perennial set of festivities: the same parties, events & etc. year after year. On the other hand "attended" implies of the set of events taking place that particular year.

Since the same set of parties, performances, and events *does* happen from year to year at Christmas, you end up with basically the same meaning in this passage either way, but you could have a more striking difference in a different passage.